# Dynamic Last Row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following code to find the last row in Sheet1 & Sheet2

```
Dim 1LastRow As Long
Dim 2LastRow As Long
1LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
2LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

This works as initially expected, however I'd like "1LastRow" to adjust to dynamically pick up the last row.

For example, if Sheet1 initially has 50 rows, but after:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B" & 2LastRow).Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Sheet1 now has 55 rows. However, "1LastRow" is still assuming that Sheet1 only has 50 rows, and thus creates inconsistencies throughout the rest of the code  when "1LastRow" is used. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you using to trigger your code from running? It's really dependent on how often the data will be updated and how the info will be used in the code. edit: typo

Comment: New data will be pasted within Sheet2 on a daily basis (a data dump), and the code will need to be executed to update the values on Sheet1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off your code won't compile in an Office VBA environment: variables names can't start with a number. So let's call them `LastRow1` and `LastRow2`, instead

second, even if there were some automagic way of making a variable self update, your code would fail since you are copying a 1-column range from `Sheet2` and pasting it starting from cell D2 of `Sheet1`, which would have no effect whatsoever in column A last row index setting

all that said, you have could use a `Function()` that returns the wanted row index.

For instance this function:

```
Function LastRow1() As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

would return `Sheet1` column D last not empty row index (well, it would actually fail should column A be totally empty, but it's an easy fix)

you could easily have it return any other column last not empty cell row index by simply changing column index in `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 4)`

so that your "main" code would look like:

```
Sub main()
    Dim LastRow2 As Long
    LastRow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B" & LastRow2).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    MsgBox LastRow1 ' this would return Sheet1 column D last not empty row index

    MsgBox Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D" & LastRow1).Address 'this would return the address of Sheet1 column D range from cell D2 down to last not empty cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Just tested this and it works perfectly. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

Well, a variable doesn't magically update itself. You see that you have code that pastes rows. Just repeat the code that sets the variable for the last row when you do something that changes the last row.

```
Dim 1LastRow As Long
Dim 2LastRow As Long
1LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
2LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B" & 2LastRow).Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
1LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Or you could use a dynamic range name with a formula along the lines of

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))
```

Then refer to that range like

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("OneLastRow").Row
```

But this will fall over if the column contains blank cells.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I believe re-setting the variable after the last row adjusts would be the best solution for my data. VBA is a new language for me, what do you mean by "repeat the code"? Doing so would create a Duplicate Error. I tried creating a new LastRow named 3LastRow just after the line of code that pastes the additional rows, but it doesn't get the last row as expected. Thanks again.

Comment: You DO know that you can set the SAME variable to a different value over and over again, right? So after your paste command, the next line should be `1LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` - no need to use a new variable name.

Comment: Again, VBA is a new language for me, and there are a few things that I wasn't able to pick up through different courses/investigating previous questions. So no, I did not know that you can set the same variable to a different value over and over again. 
But I appreciate the edit.

Comment: The very concept of a "variable" is that the value is "variable" i.e. it can change. You just need to issue the command to refresh the variable value with the value that it SHOULD now have. I am disappointed that you accepted an answer that does not really do what you describe in your question. I showed you how to adjust the variable to the value you need.  I suggest you unmark the selected answer and mark my post as the answer instead, because it does what you say you need.